# explicitly_shared

Tags: ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently using a custom action to post story to the wall.  I would like to use the explicitly_shared option but not sure where to put that parameter.  I'm using the iOS API and the the post method I'm using is

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/:"
                             graphObject:
                       completionHandler:

All help appreciated.

Thanks,

BS

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
[graphObject setObject:@"1" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
```

Comment: Where on the developer page of facebook can I enable my app to be allowed to post with `fb:explicitly_shared` set to true?